# Topology trouble

Tags: modeling, topology

I finished my male character's head, however I need to make the body in an A pose. The only problem is how do I not only capture the look, but also make sure that the topology is correct so when I rig it with armature it won't look messy when it moves around? Is there a guide or do I just have to go with my gut? Also I'm only using quads in this model.[image]

Comment: Hello, your question is probably too broad, but you have a lot of images and tutorial about how to make a human topology.

Comment: As moonboots says, If you are beginner I would suggest you to find someone work for free, download their topology, import it in your project and use it as reference to make your human topology work better. There is not 1 correct way to do this, there are multiple ones based on what is your desire... The only thing you can do is to practice and learn

Comment: I see thank you, also where can i find these free models?